# Too much blinking rows in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have `listView` with its own adapter. This is the fragment `getView` method from the adapter code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //this code works properly            
    switch(dane_status.get(position)) {
        case "zgłoszone": mojView_holder.tekst_data.setTextColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.zamZgloszColor)); break;
         default: mojView_holder.tekst_data.setTextColor(0xFFC0C0C0); //silver
    }
    //this code not working properly
    if (dane_status.get(position).equals("zgłoszone")) {
        Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(200); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
        anim.setStartOffset(20);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        convertView.startAnimation(anim);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

I'm using `Animation` to only blink the rows where the status is 'zgłoszone'. These rows really are blinking, but on my list the first row is blinking and every first row on each next "screen" - `ListView` have 11 rows visible and blinking is row 1, 13, 25, 37...

It's important that coloring date (switch instruction) works OK. I only have problems with `Animation`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the animation is continuing when you recycle the views. Try clearing any current animations using [View.clearAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation%28%29).

```
if (date_status.get(position).equals("zgłoszone")) {
    ...
} else {
    convertView.clearAnimation();
}
```

Comment: That's the point! I thought, that's animation is starting again and again but I couldn't stop it. Thank you very match!